# Linux equivalent to fsstat from Solaris or FreeBSD

Tags: linux, zfs

On Solaris, we are monitoring the activity of several filesystems in individual shares using the command:

```
fsstat -i /apool/adataset/*
```

where `apool` is the ZFS pool in which `adataset` is the parent to the many filesystems we want to monitor the IOPS of.

With the advances of OpenZFS on Linux, we have started to deploy several Linux hosted ZFS pools. While there is a `fsstat` tool on Linux ([Sleuth Kit](https://github.com/sleuthkit/sleuthkit)), it assumes one filesystem per volume, while ZFS is a pooled storage with many filesystems.

A paper addresses this question (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1742287617301901) but I cannot find a place where the extension to Sleuth Kit they describe in the paper is accessible.

Would anyone have suggestions, either an alternative method to `fsstat` on Linux or some repo with the extension for pooled storage?

Comment: I assume `zpool iostat` doesn't meet your needs because it is based on pool or vdev rather than datasets/filesystems?

Comment: Check the References in the paper. `https://github.com/fkie-cad/sleuthkit` is a URI for the modifjed `sleuthkit`'s github repository, where the changes are kept.